# Elapsed time in PLC (OMROM CX Program)

Tags: plc

[image]

I am trying to measure elapsed time.

Above ladder logic tries to measure the time for which `6000.03` is on.

It read around `6000 ms` where as my stopwatch showed around 11 seconds.

What is wrong in the logic?

EDIT:

Had tried with below logic as well but got again different results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The timer is reset in plc cycle. It cause the delays.

Make the timer run longer. About 1s and count 600 pulses. I am sure you will get lower error.

Other solution is to find system clock bit and use it. It is not plc cycle dependent. For now i cannot remember the system bit addresses for omron. If you still have problem just let know i will look for it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is right but the start/stop/reset bits maybe cause the problem?

[image]